# How to get current user name in every request made in Blazor Server project using SQL Server and EF Core using .NET 5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Approach**

I used dependency injection for a service that I wrote to get the current user name in `ApplicationDbContext`.

This is the service:

```
using System;
using Common;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace DataAccess.Service
{
    public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public string GetCurrentUserName()
        {
           return _accessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I have registered the service in the container as a `Transient` service:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.TryAddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();
```

Using dependency injection, I intend to grab the current username and timestamp whenever any model state changes, e.g. `Added` / `Modified` / `Deleted`. The following reads my `ApplicationDbContext` where `OnBeforeSaving` is my intention.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Common;
using DataAccess.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataAccess.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        private readonly string _currentUserName;
        private readonly IUserResolverService _userResolverService;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IUserResolverService userResolverService) : base(options)
        {
            _userResolverService = userResolverService;
            _currentUserName = _userResolverService.GetCurrentUserName();   
        }

        public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
        {
            OnBeforeSaving(_currentUserName);
            return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            OnBeforeSaving(_currentUserName);
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        }

        public void OnBeforeSaving(string currentUserName)
        {
            string userName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUserName) ? SD.Role_Admin : _currentUserName;
            var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e =>
                    e.State == EntityState.Added
                    || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

            foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
            {
                try
                {
                    switch (entityEntry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entityEntry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            entityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = userName;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            entityEntry.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = userName;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            entityEntry.Property("DeletedBy").CurrentValue = userName;
                            entityEntry.Property("DeletedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            break;

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public DbSet<HotelRoom> HotelRooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HotelRoomImage> HotelRoomImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HotelAmenity> HotelAmenities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AdminUser> AdminUser { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RoomOrderDetails> RoomOrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I am not able to capture the username after the first time if the `ApplicationDbContext` is used more than once in a HTTP request. The `CreatedBy` is getting captured correctly, `UpdatedBy` is getting empty.

The intention of `DeletedBy` and `DeletedAt` was to implement soft delete. Right now even after my `OnBeforeSaving` function, model objects are getting removed from DB. I believe I have to override some additional methods to that. Or is there any configuration that allows me to do the same?

I am new to Blazor, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Register your service as scoped: `services.TryAddScoped<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();`

Comment: Thank you @abdusco, this fixed my issue.